# Функциональные интерфейсы и их реализация

Tags: java

Подскажите пожалуйста способы реализации функциональных интерфейсов.

Я знаю два способа - имплементирование в класс и реализация методов

И с помощью лямбда выражений.

Какие есть еще?

Comment: Ну насколько я знаю это и все. Вт котлине вы можете просто написать функцию высшего порядка которая будет лямбдой.

Comment: суть в том, что мне говорят, что есть еще варианты, а я никак ни в доках ни на всяких сайтах найти их не могу...

Comment: А ответить на этот вопрос эти же ребята не хотят? Мне вот интересно было бы узнать

Comment: вот нифига не говорят, ищи сам говорят )

Вот я уже час сижу ищу и думаю то-ли я дурак то-ли лыжи не едут...

Comment: @СергейБувака оказывается имели ввиду ссылки на методы.....

Answer (score 6, accepted):

В Java 8 функциональные интерфейсы могут быть представлены с использованием лямбда-выражений, ссылок на методы и ссылок на конструкторы.

В документации об этом написано:

> Note that instances of functional interfaces can be created with lambda expressions, method references, or constructor references.
>   [пруф](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/FunctionalInterface.html)

Насколько мне известно, других вариантов пока не добавлялось.

Comment: Спасибо!!! Уже понял ) Надо учится внимательнее читать javadoc...

Comment: Обращу внимание, там написано "**Note that** instances of functional interfaces **can be** created with .." - **Заметьте**, что экземпляр функционального интерфейса **может быть** создан с...   Но это не исключает явное использование анонимного класса и упомянутую ТСом имплементацию, так как это, всё-таки, интерфейсы